# Count DownTimer in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation that extends Fragment Activity.

What I want to do

When I open the navigation I want to start the count Down Timer.

Then when I access a fragment from the navigation I want to populate two text views with the values of minutes and seconds from the count Down Timer, and while I am on this fragment the text views to be updated with values from count Down Timer.

How can I provide that?

Many thanks :).

In navigation:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_activity, null);

TextView remainedMinTextView = (TextView) v
        .findViewById(R.id.remainedMinTextView);
TextView remainedSecTextView = (TextView) v
        .findViewById(R.id.remainedSecTextView);
Utils.startCountDownTimer(10000, remainedMinTextView, remainedSecTextView);
```

in utils class i create the count down timer

```
public static void startCountDownTimer(final long milis,
    final TextView remainedMinTextView,
    final TextView remainedSecTextView) {

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milis, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            remainedMinTextView.setText(""
                    + String.format("%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

            remainedSecTextView
                .setText(""
                + String.format(
                "%d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                .toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
                - TimeUnit.MINUTES
                .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}
```

In the fragment where I have the two text views

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_activity, null);

    // minutes/seconds passed in app
    remainedMinTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.remainedMinTextView);
    remainedMinTextView.setTypeface(Utils.TypeFace(getActivity()));

    remainedSecTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.remainedSecTextView);
    remainedMinTextView.setTypeface(Utils.TypeFace(getActivity()));
}
```

Ok here when I click on 5 minutes for example (here is where the text views are updated)

```
textViewTimer5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTimer5);
textViewTimer5.setTypeface(Utils.TypeFace(getActivity()));

textViewTimer5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Utils.startCountDownTimer(300000, remainedMinTextView, remainedSecTextView);
    }
});
```

If I call the count down from here it works... but what I need is when I open the navigation and start the count down and then I open the the fragment that contains the two text views to be updated with values from count down.

Comment: I think the documentation for CountDownTimer shows a good example of what you are trying to do: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onTick(long)

Comment: Hello, i've tried the example, If i am on the fragmnet and run the count down timer onCreateView it works ok, it populates the two text view, but I don;t know to do that from other view to send values to fragment and update them while count down timer is still onTick. Many thanks:)

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: Hello and sry for the delay. I've modify my code by still don;t get the result i wanted. What I tried: In navigation fragment activity on start I tried to get the view where the seconds and minutes are.